# Beautifulsoup Table Scraping table navigation

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am trying to learn beautifulsoup to scrap HTML and have a difficult challenge.
HTML I am trying to scrap is not well formatted and with lack of knowledge with beautifulsoup I am kind of stuck..

The HTML I am trying to scrap is as below

```
<table>
 <tr>
    <td><b>Value 1<b/>HiddenValue1</td>
    <td>Value 2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>NoValue</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td><b>Value 3<b/>HiddenValue2</td>
    <td>Value 4</td>        
 </tr>     
</table>
```

So the outcome I am trying to get is extract all rows with two td tags.
This will extract the first and the last tr.
Once I get them, I need to arrange these td and b and just text into dictionary.

My desired outcome is list of dictionary

```
[ 
  { tdb : 'Value 1', tdHidden : 'HiddenValue1', tdSecond : 'Value 2' },
  { tdb : 'Value 3', tdHidden : 'HiddenValue2', tdSecond : 'Value 4' },
]
```

I am trying to use findall() function but don't know how to check length of children td tags and also not to sure how to navigate to first td and second td ..

Thanks in advance for your help !

**EDIT :**

Could you please also help with how to get "GetThisValue" and "Current" with in the td tag?

```
<td align="left" valign="top">
   <b>Value1</b>
   <br>
   <font>
     <b>Current</b>
   </font>
   <br>
   GetThisValue
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code should work -

```
trs = soup.find('table').find_all('tr')
trs = [tr for tr in trs if len(tr.find_all('td')) == 2]
results = []
for tr in trs:
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    d = {
        'tdb': tds[0].b.text,
        'tdHidden': tds[0].b.next_sibling,
        'tdSecond': tds[1].text
    }
    results.append(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer2 for the EDIT part -

```
# GetThisValue
soup.find('td').find_all('br')[1].next_sibling

# Current
soup.find('td').find('font').b.text
```